# HTML5 Database Transactions

Tags: database, html

i am wondering abt the example [W3C Offline Web Apps](http://www.w3.org/TR/offline-webapps/) the example

```
function renderNotes() {
  db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Notes(title TEXT, body TEXT)', 
      []);
    tx.executeSql(‘SELECT * FROM Notes’, [], function(tx, rs) {
      for(var i = 0; i < rs.rows.length; i++) {
        renderNote(rs.rows[i]);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

has the create table before the 'main' `executeSql()`. will it be better if i do something like

```
$(function() {
    // create table 1st
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Notes(title TEXT, body TEXT)', 
          []);
    });

    // when i execute say to select/modify data, i just do the actual action
    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql(‘SELECT * FROM Notes’, [], function(tx, rs) {
            ...
        }
    });

    db.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql(‘INSERT ...’, [], function(tx, rs) {
            ...
        }
    });
})
```

i was thinking i don't need to keep repeating the `CREATE IF NOT EXISTS` right?

#### Update

```
function initDatabase() {
    notes = openDatabase("todolist", "1.0", "To-Do List", 1*1024*1024, function (notes) {
        notes.changeVersion("", "1.0", function(tx) {
            tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE todolist (id INTEGER, task TEXT)", [], function(tx, rs) {
                alert("Table created");
            });
        }); 
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You address this by using `changeVersion`. The API supports database versioning so you can apply schema changes during upgrades, or in your case.. installation.

There are some examples in the [documentation](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webdatabase/):

```
function prepareDatabase(ready, error) {
  return openDatabase('documents', '1.0', 'Offline document storage', 5*1024*1024, function (db) {
    db.changeVersion('', '1.0', function (t) {
      t.executeSql('CREATE TABLE docids (id, name)');
    }, error);
  });
}
```

In that example, they call `prepareDatabase`, which opens a connection to the database, but if the version is < 1.0 or non-existent, it calls that closure which executes the `CREATE TABLE` statement.

When the page is revisited, assuming the user didn't clear out the database.. it will be at version 1.0 already, so `changeVersion` will simply do nothing instead of running the `CREATE TABLE` again.

Comment: what do the 1st parameter do? i guess 2nd is the version to update to and the last, method to use when the version is < 1.0. btw, i must run prepare database before running a `executeSql`?

Comment: @jiewmeng - the first parameter is the "old version" (in this case none)

Comment: what if i use `db.changeVersion("1.0", "2.0", function(tx) { ... })`. it will update if the version is *exactly* 1 or less that 1 or?

Comment: @jiewmeng - it won't be less than 1. I don't know if it will trigger for 1.2, 1.3, etc ... best thing you can do is try it to find out

Comment: i seem to find that changeVersion() is not run ... even when its the 1st time the application starts up.